# How can I connect to a windows aws virtual machine using python?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

Is there a library that I can use to connect to a remote windows aws machine? 
I need just to simulate login and logout.

Answer (score 0):

We most likely need more information about what you are trying to do.

You will probably need to use something like `rdpy` (to login with the Windows Remote Desktop Protocol) assuming you don't have an ssh server already installed on it. [Docs here](https://pypi.org/project/rdpy/)

Alternatively, you can invoke your rdp client of choice with something like `subprocess`